# Send AlertDialog Positive Button Call to Custom View

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to send the `AlertDialog` positive button event of an `DialogFragment` to my custom view `CustomViewGroup` which is embedded three times in Activity `Overview`.

I followed the guide from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents which passes positive button call to overriden method `onDialogPositiveClick` in activity. In my case there should no need to handle this in activity Overview.

**How is it possible to call method `processInput` of custom view class after positive button click in AlertDialog?**

The following structure should give you an overview (naming is generalized here):

**ACTIVITY**

```
public class Overview extends AppCompatActivity implements MyDialogFragment.DialogListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.overview);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final CustomViewGroup cvg1 = (CustomViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.first_view_group);
        // TODO Custom listener for onDialogPositiveClick needed?

        // TODO CustomViewGroup 2 and 3
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // Is called for each of my three CustomViewGroup instances 
        // after clicking positive button in AlertDialog.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // Not needed
    }
}
```

with layout of Overview activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.my.project.views.CustomViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/first_view_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.my.project.views.CustomViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/second_view_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.my.project.views.CustomViewGroup
        android:id="@+id/third_view_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CUSTOM VIEW GROUP**

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends LinearLayout {

        public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            // process some attributes, not relevant here, remove from layout too

            setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            final AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getContext();

            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view_group, this, true);

            final Button mButton = (Button) getChildAt(1);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final DialogFragment dialog = CodeViewGroup.newInstance();
                    dialog.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogFragment");
                }
            });
        }

        public static DialogFragment newInstance() {
            DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();

            // pass arguments to dialog, not relevant here

            return dialog;
        }

        public void processInput(DialogFragment dialog) {
            // do some stuff with AlertDialog input
        }
    }
```

with layout of custom view group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_group_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view_group_label_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/view_group_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view_group_button_text" />

</merge>
```

**MYDIALOGFRAGMENT**

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface DialogListener {
        void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);

        void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    DialogListener mListener;    

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_title))
                .setView(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(MyDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(MyDialogFragment.this);
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Activity activity;

        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            if (context instanceof Activity) {
                activity = (Activity) context;
                // Instantiate the DialogListener so we can send events to the host
                mListener = (DialogListener) activity;
            } else {
                mListener = (DialogListener) context;
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement DialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

with layout of dialogfragment "my_dialog_fragment":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_edit_text"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope, there is no typo in snippets after renaming and consolidation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use AlertDialog for showing dialog box with custom view?

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Check this link to how to use AlertDialog with custom view.

This is very simple and effective method.

You can add Positive Button, Negative Button, Neutral Button to dialog.

http://android.pcsalt.com/create-alertdialog-with-custom-layout-using-xml-layout/

Comment: Hi Ankesh. This works like a charm. I have had removed the MyDialogFragment java code and integrated my_dialog_fragment layout to my custom view like described in your link.

Comment: Thanks, I think using this you need not to create so many java classes. Simple create alertdialog and set your custom view to it.